Derivation of equality for complex numbers
While reading "Functions of one complex variable" from John B. Conway I stumbled upon this equality
$\frac{\mid z^k-w^k\mid}{\mid z-w\mid}=\mid z^{k-1}+z^{k-2}w+...+zw^{k-2}+w^{k-1}\mid$
Could someone explain to me how to derive this?
Thanks in advance.

Multiply $ z^{k-1}+z^{k-2}w+...+zw^{k-2}+w^{k-1}$ by $z-w$ and see what you get.

I'll just add that you surely know that $z^2-w^2=(z-w)(z+w)$. So here is a generalization for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
